# Comments only visible in same Project - Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, comments

well the title says everything. I've got a class with some comments in it.
Something like

```
/// <summary>
/// Bla
/// </summary>
```

The problem is, I can only see those comments inside the project. If I make an reference to this class and use it in an other project, the comments are not visible...

Answer (score 0):

If the project is in the same solution, you can replace the reference with a project reference (the Solution tab in Add Reference).

If not, you need to open Project Properties in the original project and check Generate XML Documentation File in the Build tab.